# Inital Value Problem from general solution

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have the following matrix:

$\frac{d\mathbf{Y}}{dt} = \begin{pmatrix} -3 & -5 \\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\mathbf{Y}$

And the inital condition:

$\mathbf{Y_0} = (4,0)$

I have got the correct general solution

$\mathbf{Y}(t) = k_1e^{-t}\begin{pmatrix} -2 \cos \sqrt{11} t -\sqrt{11} \sin \sqrt{11}t  \\ 3 \cos \sqrt{11} t \end{pmatrix} + k_2e^{-t}\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{11} \cos \sqrt{11} t -2\sin \sqrt{11}t  \\ 3 \sin \sqrt{11} t \end{pmatrix}.$

So my first step was to get $\mathbf{Y}(0)$:

$\mathbf{Y}(0) = k_1e^{0}\begin{pmatrix} -2 \cos (\sqrt{11} * 0) -\sqrt{11} \sin( \sqrt{11}*0)  \\ 3 \cos (\sqrt{11}* 0) \end{pmatrix} + k_2e^{0}\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{11} \cos (\sqrt{11} *0) -2\sin (\sqrt{11}*0)  \\ 3 \sin (\sqrt{11} *0) \end{pmatrix}.$

$\mathbf{Y}(0) = k_1\begin{pmatrix} -2   \\ 3  \end{pmatrix} + k_2\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{11}\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$

**So I multiplied the matrix with $\mathbf{Y_0}$: This is the error, so the comments below**

$\begin{pmatrix} -3 & -5 \\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\mathbf{Y_0}=\begin{pmatrix} -3 & -5 \\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}(4,0)=(-12,12)$

Therefore $k_1 = 4$ and $k_2 = -\frac{4}{\sqrt{11}}$

My solution is as follows:

$x(t) = 4\cdot e^{-t}\cdot (-2\cdot \text{cos}(\sqrt{11}\cdot t)-\sqrt{11}\cdot \text{sin}(\sqrt{11}\cdot t))-\frac{4}{\sqrt{11}}\cdot e^{-t}\cdot (\sqrt{11}\cdot \text{cos}(\sqrt{11}\cdot t)-2\cdot \text{sin}(\sqrt{11}\cdot t))$
$y(t)=4\cdot e^{-t}\cdot 3\cdot \text{cos}(\sqrt{11}\cdot t)-\frac{4}{\sqrt{11}}\cdot e^{-t}\cdot 3\cdot \text{sin}(\sqrt{11}\cdot t)$

But somewhere there has to be an error, but after looking at it for two hours I just can't find it...

Comment: Why multiply the matrix with $Y_0$? After putting t=0 on the right put the vector $Y_0$ on the left and equate components. You get $k_1=0$ and a + sign on your $k_2$.

Comment: This was indeed my error. No clue why I multiplied the matrix, probably a laxck of sleep.. Thanks for the help.

Comment: these eigenvalues are not nice at all.